# Deploying mvc4 to linux

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mono

I've made my first website in ASP.NET MVC 4 for a customer, and he bought a host at 1eurohosting.net. On their website's FAQ it says

"Do you offer Windows based services?
We do not. We only offer Linux based services."

I've read that its still possible to run a MVC4 application on linux using mono, but how would I do this?

What I've tried so far is publish the website by right clicking solution explorer, and following the steps when u click "publish". The publishing works fine, and the files are on the webserver, but it doesn't run, because I think I need to use mono.

I don't know what to do at this point. What do I do next? If I have to use mono, how can I use it?

Comment: Does the web host offer Mono on their servers?

Comment: @StevenV It doesn't say anything about mono. Does this mean it doesn't offer this?

Comment: I would doubt Mono is offered in that case. I'm not sure how the web server would be able to run the website because the web server has to understand how to communicate with mono to execute and serve the deployed code.

Comment: @StevenV is mono something that the host has to install?

Comment: More than likely they would need to install Mono, and configure Apache (or the web server they are using) to know how to handle Mono based websites. I wish you luck trying to get them to even entertain the idea, or to have a support agent that understands the request.

Comment: @stevenV thank you, I'm just going to try and contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I either need a host that supports IIS or Mono. I dont think my current webhost supports Mono, I am still going to try and contact them, though.