# Host/Deploy ASP.NET MVC to docker using linux container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, ubuntu, docker, asp.net-core

I'm pretty new to docker and its containers. My question simply, is it possible to deploy ASP.NET MVC 4/5 to docker on linux container. I found some links here on stackoverflow but nothing is suitable for my case:

1- [Can we deploy an asp.net mvc 4 app to docker with windows container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642876/can-we-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-4-app-to-docker-with-windows-container)
 (Windows container not Linux container

2- [How to deploy asp.net application to docker container on Linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085314/how-to-deploy-asp-net-application-to-docker-container-on-linux-server)
 (.NET core not ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: you may, if you install and configure mono. see related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189164/deploying-mvc4-to-linux

Answer (score -1):

right now, its possible, microsoft created docker package https://www.docker.com/microsoft
six months ago NET Core was on 1.xx, and now is completed with ASP net core
https://www.maherjendoubi.io/asp-net-core-2-0-in-docker/
as you can see now you can reach that goal

Comment: The links you provided are for ASP.net *core* and not a traditional ASP.net app

Comment: there is no official asp.net for linux just asp core alternative